# Waiting for model's data to be loaded using jQuery when -- experiencing timing differences?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, jquery-deferred

I have an MVC application. I am trying to load a model from the server using jQuery's load. This works perfectly fine. I am now trying to run some JavaScript after all of my views have been loaded. As such, I am introducing jQuery's deferred promise functionality through use of [jQuery .when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

My limited understanding of this functionality has lead me to believe that the two bits of code below should run identically. It seems to me that my 'then' method is executing too soon, though. I'm not sure how to confirm that.

**Old Code (Works):**

```
$('#OrderDetails').load('../../csweb/Orders/OrderDetails', function () {
    $("fieldset legend").off('click').click(function () {
        var fieldset = $(this).parent();
        var isWrappedInDiv = $(fieldset.children()[0]).is('div');

        if (isWrappedInDiv) {
            fieldset.find("div").slideToggle();
        } else {
            fieldset.wrapInner("<div>");
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
            fieldset.find("div").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, I would like to extend that to wait for multiple load events. To keep things simple, though, I am just going to try and wait for OrderDetails:

**New Code (Doesn't Work):**

```
var onDisplayLoadSuccess = function () {
    console.log("Done!");
    console.log('Fieldset legend:', $('fieldset legend'); //Not all found.
    $("fieldset legend").off('click').click(function () {
        var fieldset = $(this).parent();
        var isWrappedInDiv = $(fieldset.children()[0]).is('div');

        if (isWrappedInDiv) {
            fieldset.find("div").slideToggle();
        } else {
            fieldset.wrapInner("<div>");
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
            fieldset.find("div").slideToggle();
        }
    });
};

var onDisplayLoadFailure = function () {console.error("Error.");};

$.when($('#OrderDetails').load('../../csweb/Orders/OrderDetails')).then(onDisplayLoadSuccess, onDisplayLoadFailure);
```

I do not see any errors fire. I see 'Done' print to the console, but the timing seems to be different. Legends which existed on the page prior to calling when/load/then have the click event applied to them, but legends which are loaded from in the view given back by OrderDetails **do not** have the click event bound to them.

By contrast, the old code's success function applied the click event to all legends appropriately. Why would this be the case?

Comment: If you are adding elements to the DOM, you should be using .live() I believe - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @David as the page you linked to states, `.live()` is deprecated and should not be used. `.on()` is the new way for jQuery 1.7+, and `delegate()` is preferred for older versions.

Comment: @MrOBrian Ok, my bad, have you tried using `.on()` :-P?

Comment: @David The jQuery DOM element selector $('fieldset legend') does not know of the legends added to the DOM when fired from 'then.' To be sure, I just modified my .click to .on('click'), but I experienced the same results as with .click

Comment: Fifth paragraph under "Direct and delegated events" @ http://api.jquery.com/on/ ... I believe you need to delegate events so it can detect ones added, as apparently on() doesn't do future events unlike live.

Comment: You'd use: `$('fieldset').on('click', 'legend', function(){`

Comment: Thanks. The fieldsets were not loaded, either, but I am able to set a deferred event from the div loading the model's data. Feel free to respond as an answer so that I am able to accept.

Comment: @MrOBrian: You are correct indeed about delegate for pre 1.7 (well, since 1.4.2 when delegate was added to replace live, which was added in 1.3.0). I looked at the 1.6 jQuery source and found though that delegate is calling live anyway, so I don't understand the difference myself exactly unless it further optimises the implementation. The same goes for `bind()`, `click()` (and the other shortcuts) in 1.8 (didn't check 1.7) they all call `on`, so one might as well always use `on` when using 1.7 or later. Off course, using the overwrites as required for static or dynamic bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture events on DOM elements that are added dynamically after binding an Event, you need to delegate it (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Something like:

`$('fieldset').on('click', 'legend', function(){`